# Why install symfony version 4?

Tags: symfony4

I want to install version 4 symfony , 
but when I use the compose composer-project symfony / website-skeleton demo, 
it is version 5 downloaded by default ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried running using the following command:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project 4.4.99
```

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]                                           
  Could not find package symfony/website-skeleton with version 4.4.0.

Comment: @Moslah can you try `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project 4.4.99`

Comment: composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:~4.9.9 my_project

Comment: `composer create-project symfony/skeleton Stage_App "4.4.*"` seems to be more generic. (see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781558/i-cant-install-a-specific-version-of-symfony-using-composer )