# I cant install a Specific version of Symfony using Composer

Tags: symfony, cmd, composer-php, version, wamp

I want to install Symfony 4.0.6 version! using composer with cmd
when I write

```
composer create-project Symfony/framework-standard-edition Stage_App  "4.0.*"
```

also tried

```
composer create-project Symfony/skeleton  Stage_App  "4.0.*"
```

and both install Symfony 5.0.2

note: I don't want to work with the last version! i just want to work with 4.0.6

how can I install that version?

Answer (score 6):

since the `4.0.*` of symfony version is deprecated, the `symfony/skeleton` creates a project on the `5.0` version.

Since `4.4.*` version is always supported, you need to upgrade to `4.4` version and install project like this:

`composer create-project symfony/skeleton Stage_App "4.4.*"`

If you really want to get the `4.0.6` version you could always update all `symfony` dependencies in the composer.json and update them with `composer update symfony/*` but you will have other errors because folder architecture has changed so I do not recommend it.

Comment: I tried composer create-project symfony/skeleton Stage_App "4.4.*" and it worked and i installed version 4.1.13 !

Answer (score 0):

As unfortunate as it's, you can't download version 4.0.6 anymore (tried it).

As for how to download an older version, the [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications) says to do this:

```
symfony new my_project_name --version=4.4
```

Comment: i did

composer create-project symfony/skeleton Stage_App "4.1.*" and i installed version 4.1.13 ! i hope it works fine for me